# How to do an MSBuild copy command that doesn't overwrite existing files?

Tags: msbuild

Looking at the [documentation for the Copy task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx), I don't see an obvious way to copy files without overwriting existing files at the destination. I only want to copy new files.

What I have so far:

```xml
<ItemGroup> 
  <Packages Include=".nuget-publish\*.*"  />
</ItemGroup>

<Copy SourceFiles="@(Packages)" DestinationFolder="\\server\nuget\packages\" />
```

Comment: Ah! By "I only want newer files" I assumed we were looking at date stamps, but you want copy to occur only when the destination file doesn't already exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your link there is an attribute "SkipUnchangedFiles".  Add that to the copy task and set it to "true".

```
<Copy SourceFiles="@(Packages)" DestinationFolder="\\server\nuget\packages\" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
```

EDIT: 
I set up a sample project with the following.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup> 
        <ExistingPackages Include="dest\*.*" />
        <Packages Include="src\*.*" Exclude="@(ExistingPackages -> 'src\%(FileName)%(Extension)')" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="Build">
        <Message Text="PackagesToCopy @(Packages)" Importance="high" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Folder + file taxonomy is:

```
src\
    doc1.txt
    doc2.txt
    doc3.txt
    doc4.txt
    doc5.txt
    doc6.txt
dest\
    doc2.txt
    doc4.txt
    doc6.txt
CopyNew.proj
```

When I run `msbuild.exe CopyNew.proj`, I get the following output:

```
Build:
  PackagesToCopy src\doc1.txt;src\doc3.txt;src\doc5.txt
```

So now @(Packages) no longer contains the files that exist in the destination folder!

Comment: Not the same thing. The file may have changed in the source, but it should no longer be overwritten. I don't want to overwrite the file with the changes.

Answer (score 8):

Condition attribute can be used to filter source files:

```
<Copy SourceFiles="@(SourceFiles)" DestinationFiles="$(DestinationPath)%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" Condition="!Exists('$(DestinationPath)%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
```

Answer (score -1):

The `SkipUnchangedFiles="true"` option copies files only if a source file is newer than destination file.

Sometimes, you need to copy only files that do not exist in destination folder without any file date comparison. In this case you may use condition on Copy task:

```
<Copy SourceFiles="%(Packages.Identity)" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" Condition="!(Exists(@(Packages->'$(TargetDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')))" />
```

Comment: Just a note that SkipUnchangedFiles will skip a file `if they have the same size and the same last modified time` (as per the documentation). That's not the same as `copies files only if a source file is newer than destination file.`